# How to get a field with a relationship in a view

Tags: views, entities

I have a design where a `car` belongs to a `brand` and let's say a brand belongs to a`category`, using entity reference module I was able to display the brand in the car view, but I don't know how to display the category, I tried to set the relationship but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. Add a relationship of `brand` to the view. This will get you to display the properties and fields of the `brand` entity.
2. Add another relationship for the `brand` field which references to the `category` entity using the entity reference field. This relationship should use the previous relationship (like nested relationships).
3. Now you should be able to display the properties and fields of the `category` entity as well.

**Note:** I've written this generically; it should work for any type of entities (e.g. Nodes, Users, Files, Taxonomy, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to select the content type of the filter, I have a question though, why can't I see the title of the other Content types in my view ?